# requests.post() не публикует информацию

Tags: python, requests

Всем привет! У меня есть скрипт, который берет ключи с сервера (веб сайта) и запрашивает ключ у пользователя. Если ключ пользователя есть на сервере, то всё удачно. Также есть админ-панель в которой можно публиковать ключи, но они не публикуются. Что делать?

```
import requests
import json

content_keys = requests.get("http://therussiaweather.atwebpages.com/keys.txt")
content_admin = requests.get("http://therussiaweather.atwebpages.com/admin.txt")

keys_list = content_keys.json()
admin_list = content_admin.json()

user_key = input("Введите ключ: ")

if user_key == "admin":
    admin_key = input("Введите ключ от АП: ")
    if admin_key in admin_list:
        print("1 - добавление ключа")
        cmd = input(">>> ")
        if cmd == "1":
            new_key_name = input("Введите новый ключ: ")
            keys_list.append(new_key_name)
            print(keys_list)
            requests.post("http://therussiaweather.atwebpages.com/keys.txt", json=keys_list)
    else:
        print("Ключ от АП не подошел")
elif user_key in keys_list:
    print("Активировано")
else:
    print("Ключ не найден")
```

Comment: Нужно проверять результат post запроса. Как минимум - сохранять его в переменную (допустим, response), и вызывать `response.raise_for_status()`, чтобы кидало ошибку при не успешном HTTP коде результата. И даже если не упадет, смотреть текст ответа, т.к. статус может быть 200 (ОК), а в теле ответа какая-то ошибка написана.

Comment: В целом, полезно на каждом ответе проверять статус, чтобы не гадать, почему вдруг падает при конвертации ответа в json.